# Someone has SSH access to my server but I can't figure out how?

Tags: git, ssh, cpanel, whm

I have a dedicated server with WHM/cPanel and I'm looking after a site on it using git.

I have been pushing commits to the server and decided to check the logs and noticed there was another person who is also pushing changes to the server.

I have changed all server passwords (root and the cPanel user, there are no other users), there are no SSH keys in cPanel, there is only one SSH key in WHM for root user (which I added with my own passphrase).
There are no FTP users.

Are there any other ways someone could be accessing the server? Maybe a setting/page I'm missing in WHM/cPanel?

EDIT:
The changes being made by this other person are not malicious. They seem like pretty decent changes in-fact.
I have tried to contact this person but there had been no response.
The git repo is on the server and is owned by 'root' so the only way I can think of someone accessing it is via SSH - I might be wrong here, I'm only new to all of this :\

Comment: What are the permissions on the git repository and who is in the `sudo` group? If only you have write permissions on the git repo, and no one is sudo or has root access, then I don't see how someone could push to the repository

Comment: "*there was another person who is also pushing changes to the server*" - who is this person? Are the commits malicious? i.e. it is not clear from your question whether this is an attempt to crack your website. How do you know the connection is via ssh? Did you check to see recent ssh login attempts? Here's how: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/127432/87169

Comment: Is it yourself pushing changes from another computer?

Comment: @hbhb - Only root is in the sudo group

Comment: @ArjunShankar - Only root is in the sudo group, the changes were not malicious, I believe it was via SSH since it was a git push and the git repo is only available to root and I've changed the root password

Comment: @Ogday - it wasn't me, I would have recognised the commit comments :\

Comment: "the git repo is only available to root" ← That sounds risky. Why is your server configured this way?

Comment: @chris - That's what I thought as well. The previous developer for the site set it up this way. I tried to update the user/group to the cPanel user but then all my commits were showing 'permission denied' when I tried to push them, so I had to revert my changes.

Comment: Look at /var/log/secure (RH), /var/log/auth.log (debian), or the equivalent for your OS. This should show you what user is authenticating around the time of the commits. If they are connecting remotely, it should also capture the source of the connection.

Comment: First. Move ypour repo to user account. It's bad practise use root account for other all pourposes. Second review your git log. Use **git log** for see changes. Third a best practise it's config git with use ssh or https. Now, your porblem it's other. If your git it's not public, and a person acces to git repo, this person has root credentials. That is a signal or comprose system. I thonk your are missed some information. Git it's not a software for toot. Usually, all manual speak about use Apache for config. Also you must put correct permission on git server directories, setup apache, ...

Answer (score 1):

To check the details of the users who logged in the server and track their IP address and to know the commands which they are executing currently you need use the command **w** i have given example of output of command below:

```
root@ping [~]# w
 00:15:17 up 73 days, 12:29,  2 users,  load average: 0.54, 0.31, 0.38
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     tty1     -                16Jan16 49days  0.01s  0.01s -bash
root     pts/0    125.62.97.30     00:15    1.00s  0.03s  0.00s wping
```